# PyQt or PySide: QTextEdit deselect all

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside, qtextedit, deselect

I'm using PySide(PyQt is fine as well) and I want to deselect everything inside a QTextEdit. Selecting everything is very easy and it's done by self.textedit.selectAll(), but I can't find a simple way to deselect everything. Is there a straightforward way to do it that I'm not aware of or is it more complicated than that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to first get the `QTextCursor` for the `QTextEdit`

```
my_text_cursor = my_text_edit.textCursor()
```

Then clear the selection of the `QTextCursor`

```
my_text_cursor.clearSelection()
```

Then update the `QLineEdit` with the new `QTextCursor` (see [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#textCursor) for `QTextEdit.textCursor()` which indicates updating the returned `QTextCursor` does not actually affect the `QTextEdit` unless you also call the following)

```
my_text_edit.setTextCursor(my_text_cursor)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. But it's strange really, QTextEdit not having a good way to deselect everything while QLineEdit has...

Answer (score 1):

It same too, isn't it?

`QLineEdit.deselect (self)` Text all in your object.

Example;

```
.
myQLineEdit = QLineEdit()
.
.
myQLineEdit .selectAll()
.
.
myQLineEdit.deselect()
.
```

**Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#deselect

---

Or, did your want to deselect all `QLineEdit`, your just find Children is a `QLineEdit` and deselect it all;

```
myQWidget= QWidget()
.
.
listsMyQLineEdit = myQWidget.findChildren(QLineEdit)
for myQLineEdit in listsMyQLineEdit:
    myQLineEdit.deselect()
.
.
```

---

Regards,

Comment: That's true only for QLineEdit, QTextEdit doesn't have that for some strange reason...